# php htmlentities($str) with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm echoing quotes through htmlentities($str) and it works the first time, but it's for caption's on images that are being swapped via jQuery when clicked- then the caption shows the html entity `&quot;`.

How can I echo the text with quotes so that it still appears as a " instead of the $quot; after clicked?

Here's my html

```
<div class="smallImageWrapper">
      <?php if(empty($row_rsPTN['img1'])): echo "" ?>
      <?php else: ?>
      <span class="smallImage"><img src="../images/products/pbetn/50x50/<?php echo $row_rsPTN['img1']; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsPTN['img1caption']); ?>" name="smallImage" id="smallImage1" height="50px" width="50px" /></span>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

and here's my jQuery to swap the images:

```
$("#smallImage1").bind("click", function() {
  $("#largeimage").attr("src","../images/products/pbetn/180x280/<?php echo $row_rsPTN['img1']; ?>");
  $("#largeimage").attr("alt","<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsPTN['img1caption']); ?>");
  $(".caption").text("<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsPTN['img1caption']); ?>");
});
```

here's a link to my test site where you can see it occurring:
http://www.imsmfg.com/new/test/products/ptn.php?menuproduct=Lacing%20Strips

Let me know if you need more info.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$("#largeimage").attr("alt","<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsPTN['img1caption']); ?>");
```

To this:

```
$("#largeimage").attr("alt","<?php echo addslashes($row_rsPTN['img1caption']); ?>");
```

jQuery entitizes things automatically, so you don't need to put entities in that quote. You just need to escape any quotes. Hence `addslashes`.

Comment: Okay, now I have this error: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function addslahses() in D:\Web Sites\public_html\new\test\products\ptn.php on line 197"

Comment: Was a typo. Fixed. (supposed to be "addslashes", not "addslahses").

Comment: Awesome! Sorry, should've caught that. I've been scratching my head on this all day. Thank you so much!